# Reference part of the parameter in Jenkins plugin "publish over cifs"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

ALL

Below is my jenkinsfile. I defined a parameter "SVN_TAG" for listing SVN tags. The format of SVN tag is "VERSION-Digit.Digit.Digit". Now I can only only reference the whole parameter in the cifsPublisher "RemoteDirectory" settings. But I want only reference the digit part of the parameter(like "2.2.2"), how should I do this? thanks.

---

```
// Jenkins Declarative Pipeline
def PRODUCT_VERSION
pipeline {
    
    agent { label 'Windows Server 16 Node' }
    
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10', artifactNumToKeepStr: '10'))
    }
    environment {
      
        TAG = '${SVN_TAG.substring(SVN_TAG.indexOf(\'-\')+1)}'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Initialize') {
            steps {
                 script {
                    PRODUCT_VERSION = "3.2.0.1"
                 }
            }
         } 
         stage('Setup parameters') {
            steps {
                script { 
                    properties([
                        parameters([
                             [ $class: 'ListSubversionTagsParameterDefinition', 
                              credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                              defaultValue: 'trunk', maxTags: '',
                              name: 'SVN_TAG', 
                              reverseByDate: false,
                              reverseByName: true,
                              tagsDir: 'https://svn-pro.xxxx.net:xxxxxx',
                              tagsFilter: ''
                            ],                        
                        ])
                    ])
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {           
                 cleanWs()
                 checkoutSource()
                 buildSource()
                 buildInstaller()           
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {     
                copyArtifacts()
            }  
        }
    }
   
}



def copyArtifacts() {    
             
    cifsPublisher(publishers: [[configName: 'Server', transfers: [[cleanRemote: false, excludes: '', flatten: false, makeEmptyDirs: false, noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '[, ]+', remoteDirectory: 'builds\\$JOB_BASE_NAME\\${SVN_TAG}', remoteDirectorySDF: false, removePrefix: '\\unsigned', sourceFiles: '\\unsigned\\*.exe']], usePromotionTimestamp: false, useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, verbose: true]])
    
}
```

Comment: Your environment variable idea is correct, just use `""` instead of `''` to allow string interpolation, something like `TAG = "${SVN_TAG.split('-')[1]}"`. Then use that tag wherever you need it, you can also pass it to relevant functions like `copyArtifacts`.

Comment: Thanks, Noam. I set remoteDirectory as this : 'builds\\$JOB_BASE_NAME\\${TAG}' and TAG = "${SVN_TAG.split('-')[1]}". It does not work, ${TAG} is not recognized by as cifsPublisher as a variable and it is not replaced.

Comment: As i said single quotes sting (`''`) does not support string interpolation in groovy. use `"builds\\$JOB_BASE_NAME\\${TAG}"` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution works. Why don't add a answer? I will flag it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your environment variable idea is the correct way, just use double quotes (`""`) instead of single ones (`''`) to allow string interpolation, is it only works on double quotes in groovy. You can read more in the [Groovy String Documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation).

So just use something like `TAG = "${SVN_TAG.split('-')[1]}"`.
Then use that tag wherever you need it, you can pass it to relevant functions like `copyArtifact` or just use it as is: `"builds\\$JOB_BASE_NAME\\${TAG}"`.